# Make all files and directories read-only

Tags: windows-7, read-only

I would like to ask if this is possible:

I want to make all files and folders (including all sub-directories) from folder `X` to be read-only. But if I copy the files from folder `X` to folder `Y`, which is not read-only, I want them to be editable. Is this possible?

I tried setting the `read-only` to checked in folder `X`'s properties, but it doesn't do what I expect, it sets all files' `read-only` to true, then if I copy the files they are all uneditable.

Comment: Is this on a desktop PC or Server? Is it a shared location or just a folder on a local machine?

Comment: It is a desktop PC

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 is right, that copy operations will generally carry over the existing attributes. So, your only recourse is really to fix the attributes afterward. Should be relatively easy to do with PowerShell. Doesn't seem quite dead-simple, but shouldn't be too hard after a bit of Googling & testing either. Once you've got that down, you can even include it in a script that does the copy operation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy a file you also copy its attributes. Read-only is a file attribute.

So no it's not possible, at least not without some additional commands.

These commands can come in the form of you manually removing the attribute via the GUI, or manually using the command line command `attrib`, or issued via a script (ie: a batch file) that automates it for you.

If the reason you want to ensure they stay read-only until copied is because of certain users (or alike), then you should look into using the OS's file and folder permissions instead of read-only attributes.

Comment: The reason I am looking for this functionality is because I have a php framework in which projects have a specific directory structure. The folder I'm looking to make read-only is the template for a new ( empty ) project. Obviously I will not edit it on purpose but you know mistakes happen and it's not like a necessity, I was just wondering that it would be really handy if I could do that.

Comment: Sounds good, but no, there not way to do what you seek, at least not in the general sense you're asking.  If you have a specific -enough workflow you can automate it to make performing all the steps easier for you.  If you're just worried about accidental deletion and overwrites, then turn on Previous Versions and/or start making regular backups.